# Doesn't set_transient() add multiple rows with the same key?

Tags: transient

Just like `add_post_meta()` I want to add multiple `transients` with same key with different values and different timeouts, but I see that the `set_transient()` function doesn't do that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: each transient will need a unique name. Per [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/):

> If a transient exists, this function will update the transient’s expiration time.

Comment: This is very sad. I guess there is no way to simulate this with existing methods :/